# Keyboard Control by Using Haar Classifier in OpenCV?

Tags: qt, opencv

I've written a code which receives images from a webcam by using OpenCV library. In this program, I try to recognize an object (for example an arrow letter). My application recognizes the letter. Suppose I've opened a power point Presentation, I'd like my Qt application to emulate keyboard. I mean, for example, when my application detects there is a "right arrow" is in front of the webcam,it will emulate pressing "right arrow key" by keyboard, and for example if ppt is in focus, the next page in ppt is open. I also would like to be able to know how the Qt know it focus in ppt.

Is there any way to do this?

I'm using Haar classifier in opencv to detect objects.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with opencv or with Qt, for that matter, and everything to do with the target platform you are running on. You forgot to specify what platform it is.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you will need to use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be able to command keyboard characters.

Qt doesn't have any built in Keyboard commanding protocols to reach other programs.

You could also look at the [Microsoft Office SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905496.aspx).